# How to pause bokeh server updating plot based on some condition

Tags: python, bokeh, pandas-bokeh

I am using bokeh server to plot the result from my streaming frames of a video. I see Bokeh provide `add_periodic_callback` as an auto-update on the server, but I don't know how to pause it. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved by passing some global value to track the result of each update. If the global values don't change, then I will pause the update